# How to completely restore pythonpath?

Tags: pythonpath

I've had a few problems configuring a Django app (Miro Community), which was installed into a virtualenv on my Centos 6.0 Apache server.  So, I removed the virtualenv and wish to start again.

However my pythonpath still points to the python2.7.2 library that was held in the old virtualenv, so when I type $python I get:

-bash: /opt/virtual-env/mc/bin/python2.7: No such file or directory.

Rather than rebuilding the server from scratch, I would prefer to 'clean' the pythonpath and restore it back to its basic form.

Could someone please describe (or point me towards a tutorial) for cleaning out pythonpath and starting from scratch.

Currently typing $whereis python displays:

python: /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python2.6-config /usr/lib/python2.6 /usr/lib64/python2.6 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/include/python2.6 /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz